# 'serving_default' : Classification input must be a single string Tensor

Tags: tensorflow, serialization, tensorflow-serving

I'm building a very simple Classifier. The input data has the following features

```
job           object
marital       object
education     object
default        int64
housing        int64
loan           int64
contact       object
dayofmonth    object
month         object
duration       int64
campaign       int64
pdays          int64
previous       int64
poutcome      object
```

1. First version of the serving function

```
def serving_input_receiver_fn():
    feature_spec = {
        'job' : tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.string, shape = [None]),
        'marital' : tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.string, shape = [None]),
        'education' : tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.string, shape = [None]),
        'default' : tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.int64, shape = [None]),
        'housing' : tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.int64, shape = [None]),
        'loan' : tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.int64, shape = [None]),
        'contact' : tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.string, shape = [None]),
        'dayofmonth' : tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.string, shape = [None]),
        'month' : tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.string, shape = [None]),
        'duration' : tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.int64, shape = [None]),
        'campaign' : tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.int64, shape = [None]),
        'pdays' : tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.int64, shape = [None]),
        'previous' : tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.int64, shape = [None]),
        'poutcome' : tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.string, shape = [None])
    }

    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features = feature_spec, receiver_tensors = feature_spec)
```

The error is:

```
INFO:tensorflow:'serving_default' : Classification input must be a single string Tensor; got {'poutcome': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_13:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>, 'campaign': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_10:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>, 'loan': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_5:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>, 'month': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_8:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>, 'job': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>, 'duration': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_9:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>, 'education': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_2:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>, 'marital': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>, 'dayofmonth': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_7:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>, 'default': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_3:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>, 'pdays': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_11:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>, 'housing': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_4:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>, 'contact': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_6:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>, 'previous': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_12:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>}
```

Then, I changed the serving function to this:

```
def serving_input_receiver_fn():
    feature_spec = {
        'job': tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[None], dtype=tf.string),
        'marital': tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[None], dtype=tf.string),
        'education': tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[None], dtype=tf.string),
        'default': tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[None], dtype=tf.int64),
        'housing': tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[None], dtype=tf.int64),
        'loan': tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[None], dtype=tf.int64),
        'contact': tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[None], dtype=tf.string),
        'dayofmonth': tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[None], dtype=tf.string),
        'month': tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[None], dtype=tf.string),
        'duration': tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[None], dtype=tf.int64),
        'campaign': tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[None], dtype=tf.int64),
        'pdays': tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[None], dtype=tf.int64),
        'previous': tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[None], dtype=tf.int64),
        'poutcome': tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[None], dtype=tf.string)
    }

    serialized_tf_example = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.string, name='input_example_tensor')
    tf_example = tf.io.parse_example(serialized=serialized_tf_example, features=tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(feature_spec))
    receiver_tensors = {'examples': serialized_tf_example}

    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features = tf_example, receiver_tensors = receiver_tensors)
```

The error becomes:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 473, in train_and_evaluate
    return executor.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 613, in run
    return self.run_local()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 714, in run_local
    saving_listeners=saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 370, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1161, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1195, in _train_model_default
    saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1495, in _train_with_estimator_spec
    any_step_done = True
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 861, in __exit__
    self._close_internal(exception_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 894, in _close_internal
    h.end(self._coordinated_creator.tf_sess)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py", line 600, in end
    self._save(session, last_step)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py", line 619, in _save
    if l.after_save(session, step):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 519, in after_save
    self._evaluate(global_step_value)  # updates self.eval_result
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 539, in _evaluate
    self._evaluator.evaluate_and_export())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 932, in evaluate_and_export
    is_the_final_export)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 965, in _export_eval_result
    is_the_final_export=is_the_final_export))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/exporter.py", line 414, in export
    is_the_final_export)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/exporter.py", line 120, in export
    checkpoint_path=checkpoint_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 735, in export_saved_model
    strip_default_attrs=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 859, in _export_all_saved_models
    strip_default_attrs=strip_default_attrs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 925, in _add_meta_graph_for_mode
    input_receiver = input_receiver_fn()
  File "deploy_model/model.py", line 85, in serving_input_receiver_fn
    tf_example = tf.io.parse_example(serialized=serialized_tf_example, features=tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(feature_spec))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/feature_column/feature_column.py", line 806, in make_parse_example_spec
    'Given: {}'.format(column))
ValueError: All feature_columns must be _FeatureColumn instances. Given: poutcome
```

I modified the serving function again like this:

```
def serving_input_receiver_fn():
    inputs = {
        'job' : tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.string, shape = [None]),
        'marital' : tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.string, shape = [None]),
        'education' : tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.string, shape = [None]),
        'default' : tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.int64, shape = [None]),
        'housing' : tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.int64, shape = [None]),
        'loan' : tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.int64, shape = [None]),
        'contact' : tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.int64, shape = [None]),
        'dayofmonth' : tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.string, shape = [None]),
        'month' : tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.string, shape = [None]),
        'duration' : tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.int64, shape = [None]),
        'campaign' : tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.int64, shape = [None]),
        'pdays' : tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.int64, shape = [None]),
        'previous' : tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.int64, shape = [None]),
        'poutcome' : tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.string, shape = [None])
    }

    inputs = {}

    for feat in enumerate(inputs):
        inputs[feat.name] = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(shape=[None], dtype=feat.dtype)

    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(inputs, inputs)
```

Then the error changed to:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/jupyter/marketing/deploy_model/task.py", line 43, in <module>
    model.train_and_evaluate(args)
  File "deploy_model/model.py", line 136, in train_and_evaluate
    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 473, in train_and_evaluate
    return executor.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 613, in run
    return self.run_local()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 714, in run_local
    saving_listeners=saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 370, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1161, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1195, in _train_model_default
    saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1495, in _train_with_estimator_spec
    any_step_done = True
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 861, in __exit__
    self._close_internal(exception_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 894, in _close_internal
    h.end(self._coordinated_creator.tf_sess)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py", line 600, in end
    self._save(session, last_step)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py", line 619, in _save
    if l.after_save(session, step):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 519, in after_save
    self._evaluate(global_step_value)  # updates self.eval_result
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 539, in _evaluate
    self._evaluator.evaluate_and_export())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 932, in evaluate_and_export
    is_the_final_export)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 965, in _export_eval_result
    is_the_final_export=is_the_final_export))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/exporter.py", line 414, in export
    is_the_final_export)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/exporter.py", line 120, in export
    checkpoint_path=checkpoint_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 735, in export_saved_model
    strip_default_attrs=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 859, in _export_all_saved_models
    strip_default_attrs=strip_default_attrs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 932, in _add_meta_graph_for_mode
    config=self.config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1149, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/contrib/estimator/python/estimator/extenders.py", line 89, in new_model_fn
    spec = estimator.model_fn(features, labels, mode, config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 250, in public_model_fn
    return self._call_model_fn(features, labels, mode, config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1149, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/canned/dnn.py", line 811, in _model_fn
    batch_norm=batch_norm)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/canned/dnn.py", line 463, in _dnn_model_fn
    logits = logit_fn(features=features, mode=mode)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/canned/dnn.py", line 109, in dnn_logit_fn
    return dnn_model(features, mode)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 854, in __call__
    outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in converted code:
    relative to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:

    tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/canned/dnn.py:252 call  *
        net = self._input_layer(features)
    tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:854 __call__
        outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    tensorflow_core/python/feature_column/dense_features.py:133 call
        self._state_manager)
    tensorflow_core/python/feature_column/feature_column_v2.py:2835 get_dense_tensor
        return transformation_cache.get(self, state_manager)
    tensorflow_core/python/feature_column/feature_column_v2.py:2598 get
        transformed = column.transform_feature(self, state_manager)
    tensorflow_core/python/feature_column/feature_column_v2.py:2807 transform_feature
        input_tensor = transformation_cache.get(self.key, state_manager)
    tensorflow_core/python/feature_column/feature_column_v2.py:2590 get
        raise ValueError('Feature {} is not in features dictionary.'.format(key))

    ValueError: Feature campaign is not in features dictionary.
```

Finally, I solved it as follows:

```
def serving_input_receiver_fn():

    # set() change the iterable into a list of items, sorted
    feature_spec = [
        tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list('job', ['blue-collar', 'management', 'technician','admin.','services','retired', 'self-employed', \
                                                                          'entrepreneur','unemployed', 'housemaid', 'student', 'unknown']),
        tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list('marital', ['married', 'single', 'divorced']),
        tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list('education', ['secondary', 'primary', 'tertiary', 'unknown']),
        tf.feature_column.numeric_column("default"),
        tf.feature_column.numeric_column("housing"),
        tf.feature_column.numeric_column("loan"),
        tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list('contact', ['cellular', 'telephone', 'unknown']),
        tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list('dayofmonth', ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31']),
        tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list('month', ['jan', 'feb', 'mar','apr','may','jun','jul', 'aug', 'sep','oct','nov','dec']),
        tf.feature_column.numeric_column("duration"),
        tf.feature_column.numeric_column("campaign"),
        tf.feature_column.numeric_column("pdays"),
        tf.feature_column.numeric_column("previous"),
        tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list('poutcome', ['failure', 'success', 'other', 'unknown'])
    ]

    serialized_tf_example = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(dtype=tf.string, shape=[None], name='input_example_tensor')
    tf_example = tf.io.parse_example(serialized=serialized_tf_example, features=tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(feature_spec))

    receiver_tensors = {'examples': serialized_tf_example}

    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features = tf_example, receiver_tensors = receiver_tensors)
```

However, I faced another problem in prediction. I cannot provide a data format that the serving function can read.

This is the Signature_Def

```
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
  inputs['inputs'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_STRING
      shape: (-1)
      name: input_example_tensor:0
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
  outputs['classes'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_STRING
      shape: (-1, 2)
      name: dnn/head/Tile:0
  outputs['scores'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (-1, 2)
      name: dnn/head/predictions/probabilities:0
Method name is: tensorflow/serving/classify
```

This is my code of prediction

```
%%writefile ./test.json
{"inputs": {"job":"entrepreneur","marital":"married","education":"secondary","default":"1","housing":"1","loan":"1","contact":"unknown","dayofmonth":"5","month":"may","duration":"127","campaign":"1","pdays":"-1","previous":"0","poutcome":"unknown"}}

!gcloud ai-platform predict --model=campaign_deploy --json-instances=./test.json
```

The error message is:

```
{
  "error": "Prediction failed: Error processing input: Failed to convert object of type <class 'list'> to Tensor. Contents: [{'campaign': '1', 'contact': 'unknown', 'dayofmonth': '5', 'default': '1', 'duration': '127', 'education': 'secondary', 'housing': '1', 'job': 'entrepreneur', 'loan': '1', 'marital': 'married', 'month': 'may', 'pdays': '-1', 'poutcome': 'unknown', 'previous': '0'}]. Consider casting elements to a supported type."
}
```

Can anyone tell me where the problem is? Is it the input input (test.json) or the serving function? What is your suggestion to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The serving function needs to have placeholders (your second approach), but do the compat.v1 directly if you are going to be running in TF2:

```
def serving_input_receiver_fn():
    inputs = {
        'job' : tf.compat.v1.placeholder(dtype = tf.string, shape = [None]),
        'marital' : tf.compat.v1.placeholder(dtype = tf.string, shape = [None]),
      ...
    }
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(inputs, inputs)
```

The error ("campaign not in features dictionary") seems to indicate that your problem is in the equivalent of this code in creating the feature columns that are input to your DNN. Make sure put the feature_spec code with the model creation, not in the serving function:

```
feature_spec = [
        tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list('job', ['blue-collar', 'management', 'technician','admin.','services','retired', 'self-employed', \
                                                                          'entrepreneur','unemployed', 'housemaid', 'student', 'unknown']),
        tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list('marital', ['married', 'single', 'divorced']),
        tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list('education', ['secondary', 'primary', 'tertiary', 'unknown']),
        tf.feature_column.numeric_column("default"),
        tf.feature_column.numeric_column("housing"),
        tf.feature_column.numeric_column("loan"),
        tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list('contact', ['cellular', 'telephone', 'unknown']),
        tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list('dayofmonth', ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31']),
        tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list('month', ['jan', 'feb', 'mar','apr','may','jun','jul', 'aug', 'sep','oct','nov','dec']),
        tf.feature_column.numeric_column("duration"),
        tf.feature_column.numeric_column("campaign"),
        tf.feature_column.numeric_column("pdays"),
        tf.feature_column.numeric_column("previous"),
        tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list('poutcome', ['failure', 'success', 'other', 'unknown'])
    ]
```

..

```
model = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(
    feature_columns = feature_spec,
    model_dir = OUTDIR,
    ...
)
```

Comment: After modifying the codes as you suggested, the error becomes Classification input must be a single string Tensor; got {'poutcome': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_13:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>....That is the same as one of my earlier situations.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I just found that the problem is not really solved. I did not read the information clearly. The following error still appears at the end:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Signatures INCLUDED in export for Eval: None
INFO:tensorflow:Signatures INCLUDED in export for Classify: None
INFO:tensorflow:Signatures INCLUDED in export for Regress: None
INFO:tensorflow:Signatures INCLUDED in export for Predict: ['predict']
INFO:tensorflow:Signatures INCLUDED in export for Train: None
INFO:tensorflow:Signatures EXCLUDED from export because they cannot be be served via TensorFlow Serving APIs:
INFO:tensorflow:'serving_default' : Classification input must be a single string Tensor; got {'poutcome': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_13:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>, 'campaign': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_10:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>, 'loan': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_5:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>, 'month': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_8:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>, 'job': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>, 'duration': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_9:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>, 'education': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_2:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>, 'marital': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>, 'dayofmonth': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_7:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>, 'default': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_3:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>, 'pdays': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_11:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>, 'housing': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_4:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>, 'contact': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_6:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>, 'previous': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_12:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>}
INFO:tensorflow:'regression' : Regression input must be a single string Tensor; got {'poutcome': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_13:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>, 'campaign': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_10:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>, 'loan': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_5:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>, 'month': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_8:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>, 'job': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>, 'duration': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_9:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>, 'education': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_2:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>, 'marital': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>, 'dayofmonth': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_7:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>, 'default': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_3:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>, 'pdays': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_11:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>, 'housing': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_4:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>, 'contact': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_6:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>, 'previous': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_12:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>}
INFO:tensorflow:'classification' : Classification input must be a single string Tensor; got {'poutcome': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_13:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>, 'campaign': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_10:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>, 'loan': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_5:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>, 'month': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_8:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>, 'job': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>, 'duration': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_9:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>, 'education': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_2:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>, 'marital': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>, 'dayofmonth': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_7:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>, 'default': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_3:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>, 'pdays': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_11:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>, 'housing': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_4:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>, 'contact': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_6:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>, 'previous': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_12:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>}
WARNING:tensorflow:Export includes no default signature!
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from deploy_trained/model.ckpt-2500
INFO:tensorflow:Assets added to graph.
INFO:tensorflow:No assets to write.
INFO:tensorflow:SavedModel written to: deploy_trained/export/exporter/temp-1581352036/saved_model.pb
INFO:tensorflow:Loss for final step: 15.162572.
CPU times: user 1.44 s, sys: 184 ms, total: 1.62 s
Wall time: 52.6 s
```

However, I can still pass the json file to it for prediction.

```
%%writefile ./test.json
{"job":"entrepreneur","marital":"married","education":"secondary","default":1,"housing":1,"loan":1,"contact":"unknown","dayofmonth":"5","month":"may","duration":127,"campaign":1,"pdays":-1,"previous":0,"poutcome":"unknown"}

!gcloud ai-platform predict --model=campaign_deploy --json-instances=./test.json

ALL_CLASS_IDS  ALL_CLASSES   CLASS_IDS  CLASSES  LOGISTIC                 LOGITS                 PROBABILITIES
[0, 1]         [u'0', u'1']  [0]        [u'0']   [0.0004661614657379687]  [-7.6705121994018555]  [0.9995338916778564, 0.00046616149484179914]
```

I cannot see anything (i.e. empty) for the Signature Definition:

```
!saved_model_cli show --dir 'gs://first-project-09012020-1/campaign/deploy_trained/export/exporter/1581513239' --all

MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:

signature_def['predict']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['campaign'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT64
        shape: (-1)
        name: Placeholder_10:0
    inputs['contact'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1)
        name: Placeholder_6:0
    inputs['dayofmonth'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1)
        name: Placeholder_7:0
    inputs['default'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT64
        shape: (-1)
        name: Placeholder_3:0
    inputs['duration'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT64
        shape: (-1)
        name: Placeholder_9:0
    inputs['education'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1)
        name: Placeholder_2:0
    inputs['housing'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT64
        shape: (-1)
        name: Placeholder_4:0
    inputs['job'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1)
        name: Placeholder:0
    inputs['loan'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT64
        shape: (-1)
        name: Placeholder_5:0
    inputs['marital'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1)
        name: Placeholder_1:0
    inputs['month'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1)
        name: Placeholder_8:0
    inputs['pdays'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT64
        shape: (-1)
        name: Placeholder_11:0
    inputs['poutcome'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1)
        name: Placeholder_13:0
    inputs['previous'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT64
        shape: (-1)
        name: Placeholder_12:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['all_class_ids'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT32
        shape: (-1, 2)
        name: dnn/head/predictions/Tile:0
    outputs['all_classes'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1, 2)
        name: dnn/head/predictions/Tile_1:0
    outputs['class_ids'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT64
        shape: (-1, 1)
        name: dnn/head/predictions/ExpandDims:0
    outputs['classes'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1, 1)
        name: dnn/head/predictions/str_classes:0
    outputs['logistic'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 1)
        name: dnn/head/predictions/logistic:0
    outputs['logits'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 1)
        name: dnn/logits/BiasAdd:0
    outputs['probabilities'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 2)
        name: dnn/head/predictions/probabilities:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

I don't know if my deployment is successful or not.
Anyone have further suggestion to me?  Thanks

Comment: Show all the signatures in the file (not just serve, serving_default) to see what is getting used

Comment: Added above. Thank you

Comment: i don't see any difference. specify --tag_set all and omit the --signature_def to the saved_model_cli call

Comment: Sorry, I did not know I can show more. Updated above. I read through the list which seems correct.